# How to decompress bytes in Python using lzo-1.0.8 ( Python 2.7.9)?

Tags: python, byte, compression, lzo

I have a compressed byte array received from network and it is LZO Compressed. I need to decompress it using LZO. I already installed the `python-lzo-1.0.8` package for python and I checked in the Python Shell, its properly installed but I cannot find any reference on how to use the LZO Decompression or any Documentation for python-lzo. Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

You can see how to use it checking out the [test suite](https://github.com/jd-boyd/python-lzo/blob/master/tests/test.py).

In short:

```
import lzo
d = lzo.decompress(lzo_compressed_bytearray)
```

Comment: this is not clear enough, what type does the argument needs to be? I have tried <bytes> and <bytearray> after opening a file with 'rb' permissions and can't get it to work